# SQL Count Alias Possible?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to count the number of events that happened for each customer. However, the table with the events do not have the name of the customer only the ID.

So I am replacing the ID of the customer with the name from another table, but can't figure out how to count them from there. Any help would be great.

This query will show all the events but no count.

```
select
(select n.company_name from company_details n where n.delete_flag = '0' and n.company_id = u.company_id) company, 
u.company_id,
l.*
from event_logging l, user_details u
where l.created_Datetime > sysdate -1
and u.user_name = l.created_by
order by l.created_datetime desc;
```

This query will show what I want, but wont show me the names only ID.

```
SELECT created_by, count(created_by) AS CountOf
FROM event_logging
where created_datetime> sysdate -1
GROUP BY created_by
order by countof desc;
```

Sorry, trying to clean it up. New at this. Will provide more details.

Tables

| company_details N | event_logging L | user_details U |
| --- | --- | --- |
| n.company_id | l.company_id | u.company_id |
| n.company_name | l.created_by (same as u.user_id) | u.user_name |
| n.delete_flag | l.created_datetime | u.user_id ( same as l.created_by) |

Example Data

company_details N

| n.company_id | n.company_name | n.delete_flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | Donuts | 0 |
| 2B | Taxi | 0 |
| 3C | Hardware | 0 |
| D4 | Store | 0 |

event_logging L

| l.company_id | l.created_by | l.created_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 1 | 2/2/2022 |
| 2B | 2 | 2/2/2022 |
| 3C | 3 | 2/2/2022 |
| D4 | 4 | 2/2/2022 |

user_details U

| u.company_id | u.user_name | u.user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | Donuts | 1 |
| 2B | Taxi | 2 |
| 3C | Hardware | 3 |
| D4 | Store | 4 |

Query Results

First Top Query

| Company | Company_ID | u.user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Donuts | 1A | 1 |
| Donuts | 1A | 2 |
| Donuts | 1A | 3 |
| Donuts | 1A | 4 |

Second Query

| Created_by | COUNTOF |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3000 |
| 2 | 255 |
| 3 | 125 |
| 4 | 11 |

Desired Results

| Company | COUNTOF |
| --- | --- |
| Donuts | 3000 |
| Taxi | 255 |
| Hardware | 125 |
| Store | 11 |

Comment: Edit question, show all table definitions, sample data, expected output. thanks

Comment: Tip: 
[Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understood it, it is just a join of 3 tables (with some conditions):

```
select e.created_by,
       c.company_name,
       count(*) as countof
from event_logging e join user_details u on u.user_name = l.created_by
                     join company_details c on c.company_id = e.company_id
where l.created_datetime > sysdate - 1
  and c.delete_flag = '0'
group by e.created_by,
         c.company_name
order by countof desc;
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you! Sorry still a newbie at this. Much appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad if it helped.